# How to access currently requested URL in a Grails GSP file

Tags: grails, gsp

If I have a simple GSP (using Grails 2.3.6):

```
<% page import=org.me.Widget %>
<header>
    <!-- Header stuff -->
</header>
<body>
    The requested URL is <a href="${url}">${url}</a>!
</body>
```

How do I inspect the HTTP request URL (the current URL the server is responding to) and inject it into the `${url}` variable?

**Note**: I need to do this inside of GSP and not from inside a controller, if at all humanly possible, even if it is a violation of best practices.

Comment: Do you need the FULL url with protocol, host and parameters or just the path?

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaMoore (+1) actually I just need the host, but full URL would be a nice bonus.

Answer (score 3):

you could try

```
def var = request.forwardURI
```

> forwardURI - Useful for obtaining the current request URI since the request object’s requestURI property returns the original URI, not the matched one.

You can even check for additional methods added to the request object [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Servlet%20API/request.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few options in a GSP to find out the current URL.

First, you can always access the `request` object which is an [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html). Using methods such as `getRequestURL()` or `getRequestURI()`, you can inspect the request.

```
${request.getRequestURL()}
```

However, `actionName` and `controllerName` may be more useful. Both of these properties are exposed to the GSP within the model. With these you can construct the URL current using the standard `createLink` tag if needed.

```
${createLink(controller: controllerName, action: actionName)}
```

These should give you enough options to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Thanks @JoshueMoore (+1) - what if I needed some logic up at the top of the page (inside `<% %>` brackets - see above) to determine what the URL should be?

Comment: It depends on what you need for the URL. Again, do you need the full URL (protocol, host, path, and querystring)? Everything I have outlined in my answer above is available within <% %>